# Length of an Array

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so, you can create an array(EX: String[]) that holds a single value for each index by using length(), but that cannot be used for an array(EX: String[][]) that holds multiple values.

How would I pull the amount of indexes in the second mentioned array?

Comment: Are you sure you using Java?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you're trying to do? Can you add a code example?

Answer (score 1):

For 2d array

```
String[][] a=new String[4][5];

a.length     // will give row count
a[0].length // will give column count of row 0 you can change the index for other columns
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/kVLzWz)

Comment: Nooby tired mistake, was using length() instead of length, thanks got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The same way:

```
String[][] aa = // ...
System.out.println("aa has " + aa.length + " indices");
for(int i = 0 ; i < aa.length ; ++i) {
    System.out.println("aa[" + i + "] has " + aa[i].length + " indices");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of the array, you can do the same as you used to.

But if you want to get the amount of `String` objects, you can do something like this:

```
Stream.of(array).mapToInt(a -> a.length).sum()
```